# Summing certain columns SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns: Dept and Enrollment called Class. And I am trying to sum all the columns that have the same Dept.
So for example if I have:

```
Dept    Enrollment
 x         7
 y         6
 x         3
```

I want to have something like this:

```
Dept     Sum(enrollment)
x         10
y         6
```

I used this query:

```
 select Dept, sum(enrollment)  as 'Total'  from class group by dept;
```

But it is giving me an error that: the from keyword not found where expected. Why?

thank you!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please give us the exact error text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the quotes on Total no need for them. I am pretty sure that’s why you get this error.

Comment: @dani It would be good to mark the answer as accepted then (with the check mark on the left), so that other users benefit from the solution too. You can also upvote an answer if you like it (with the up-arrow) or downvote it if you don't (with the down-arrow).

Comment: This seems quite unlikely.  Most databases do allow single quotes around column aliases, although the practice is to be discouraged.